# How "adb reboot bootloader" works internally?

Tags: android, embedded, adb, bootloader

I am seeing an issue with my android images where the command `adb reboot bootloader` simply reboots back the android, instead of going to bootloader mode.

In order to fix the issue, I did some study and find that there are acually two things, `adb` and `adbd` and the host and target devices communicate using the TCP protocol over sockets.

So, the interesting thing is commands like `adb shell` and `adb devices` are working but not the `reboot bootloader`. I want to understand what the `adbd` on receiving the `reboot bootloader`. Does it change the boor order, sets some flag, changes EFI vars....?

Can you please point to some good links or understanding you can share?

PS : I am working on embedded device environ, similar to raspberry pi...

Answer (score 12):

This is how `adb reboot bootloader` works on a standard Android device connected via `USB` (the only transport supported by the standard Android bootloader in the `fastboot` mode):

1. `adb` client sends the `reboot bootloader` command to the `adb` server (over TCP)
2. `adb` server forwards the `reboot bootloader` command to the `adbd` on the device (over USB)
3. `adbd` sets the `sys.powerctl` property to `reboot,bootloader`
4. `sys.powerctl` change triggers the `init.rc` rule which runs `powerctl`  `init`'s built-in
5. which does `_NR_reboot` syscall
6. which sets the `reboot to bootloader` flag and reboots the device

On the next power up the bootloader would see the flag and go to the `fastboot` mode. But only if `USB` is connected.

Comment: @InsaneCoder [ADB](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/adb/) and [init](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/init/) etc. are open-source, so you can see how it works yourself. The kernel sources are a bit harder to dig into, partly because of how much more variation between vendors there is... :-( but mostly they reboot from a `reboot_notifier` handler. What the "bootloader" flag is, also varies greatly, and it's possible it isn't implemented on some ports.

Comment: @Alex : Thanks for this valuable info. Can you please tell where can i find this `reboot to bootloader` flag? And is the 4th point incomplete? `built-in` what?

Comment: @Alex : Oh wait... I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472761/how-does-the-bootloader-pick-up-the-command-after-a-restarting-system-with-comm

Comment: `powerctl` is an `init` built-in command. and the exact reboot and boot flag setting procedures are SoC specific

Comment: @AlexP. : I searched a lot, but no success. Where is this `reboot to bootloader` flag? I, initially thought it to be `efivars` but when I checked there are no `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars` exported at all. Even on other board, where this `adb reboot bootloader` command is working fine, these variables are not exported in userspace. That means, its implemented differently, to what I was thinking. Can you please give me a  direction?

Comment: I can not help you with that. Every SoC vendor handles it differently. This is how Qualcomm does it https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/+/android-msm-bullhead-3.10-marshmallow-dr/drivers/power/reset/msm-poweroff.c